# IF Statement, that is incorrect Probably need a SUMIF or other type of formula to work

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of days in the 1st column.

Based on the days in the 1st column I want to give each line a status i.e. if the cell A2 has a value of 5 days, in B2 I want the status to read "Less Than 10 days".

- If A1 has a value of 15, then A2 will update with a value of "10-20 Days".
- If A1 has a value of 35, then A2 will update with a value of "30-60 Days", and so on.

There are 5 groupings that I need i.e. "Less Than 10 days", "10-20", "20-30", "30-60" and "Greater Than 60 Days"

I could have numerous values on the spreadsheet in the 1st column so need to put them into a grouping bucket using some formula. Currently I am using the below , but does not seem to be working.

My formula below only partially works i.e. picks up the 1st two conditions, but cannot calculate the 3rd or 4th or 5th condition.

Any ideas?

The formula I am currently using is :

```
=IF(A19<10,"Less Than 10 days",IF(10<A19>20,"10-20 Days", IF(20<A19>30,"20-30 Days",IF(A19>30,"Greater Than 30 Days","Greater than 60 Days"))))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
=IF(A19<10,"Less Than 10 days",IF(A19<20,"10-20 Days", IF(A19<30,"20-30 Days",IF(A19<60,"Greater Than 30 Days","Greater than 60 Days"))))
```

I changed:

- made all logical operators more clear
- changed "30" to "60" in last statement (to match what your text actually is)

Follow the logic through the statements - for the first if statement, if it's not less than 10 days, it checks if it is less than 20 days, then 30 days, etc. You don't need the 10 - 20 range there - you are already handling all the `<10` values by the first `IF` sattement. Similarly values between 20-30 are handled by the `<30` part of the appropriate `IF` statement.